# Finding elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I need some help with finding the elements using webdriver.

1. On the webpage this is the label '**Password**'

`< div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group text-left">
   < label _ngcontent-c1="">Password</label >`

2.On the webpage this is the textbox for '**Password**'

```
< input _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="Password" placeholder="" type="password" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;"/>
</div >
```

3. On the webpage this is the button '**Login**'

   `< div _ngcontent-c1="" class="text-right col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 login-submit no-side-padding">
      < button _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" 
        tabindex="4" type="submit" disabled="">Login< /button >
   </ div>`

Answer (score 0):

I would've used relative XPath. You can read about it here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

In your case it would be:

1. `//input[@class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" ]`
2. `//input[@formcontrolname = "Password" and  type="password"]` (or use only one property)
3. `//div[contains(text(), "Login")]`   OR `//div[contains(@class, "login-submit")]`

Answer (score 0):

**Password field:**

```
//input[@formcontrolname="Password"]
```

**Button:**
`//div[contains(text(), "Login")]` <- make sure it's under `<div>` and not  cause I see you end your tag with `</button>`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if some locator actually finds element is to open developer console (for Chrome is **F12**) and in console tab enter locator from previous comments (xpath or css) by typing:

```
xpath: $x("xpath_locator")

css: $$("css_locator")
```

**Note:** If you use double quotes inside brackets around locator, single quotes must be used inside locator itself and vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

except "*" attribute, you can use other attributes, "*" attributes are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in my quality assurance services we can also use below methods to locate element.

**Using xpath and cssSelector:**

**Xpath for label 'Password'**:

```
String xpath = //label[contains(text(),'Password')]
```

**CSS Selector for textbox 'Password'**:

```
String css = input[formcontrolname*='Password']
```

// Here the * after formcontrolname denotes 'contains' which is denotes that find the formcontrolname that contains value 'Password'

**CSS Selector for button 'Login'**:

```
String css = button[type*='submit']
```

`CssSelector` is preferred more than `XPath` as it takes less time than `XPath`.